# What formula would I use for the following question?

Tags: combinatorics

What would the formula be to find the following...?

A mutual fund has 18 stocks in its portfolio. On a given day 4 stocks move up, 11 stay the same and 3 move down. In how many ways could this happen?

I was thinking perhaps trying to use: C(18, 11)? or perhaps C(18,4)C(11,3)?

I'm really confused by this and how to solve it. If you can please explain this that would be great!

Comment: A multinomial coefficient $\displaystyle \frac {18!} {4!11!3!}$ should do

Answer (score 0):

There are $\binom{18}{4}$ ways four of the $18$ stocks could move up.  That leaves us with $14$ stocks.  There are $\binom{14}{11}$ ways that $11$ of those stocks could stay the same.  That leaves us with three stocks, all of which must move down.  Hence, the number of ways $4$ of the $18$ stocks could move up, $11$ stay the same, and $3$ move down is 
$$\binom{18}{4}\binom{14}{11}\binom{3}{3} = \frac{18!}{4!14!} \cdot \frac{14!}{11!3!} \cdot \frac{3!}{3!0!} = \frac{18!}{4!11!3!}$$
which agrees with @BGM's answer in the comments.